What are the existing and general future electrical loads on the lunar surface, and does their voltage level matter?
Do we currently have some clear pre-existing types of base loads, and is there a standardized voltage level for electrical equipment? If not, does it make sense to consider future loads and develop a standard on the Moon?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There should be contract and proposal documents for Artemis that are more specific, but  this science sample freezer (page three of this PDF) lists Orion as 120V DC, Gateway as 28V DC and 120V DC, and Human Landing System as 28V DC and 120V DC.
This voltages are not unexpected as 28V DC is a somewhat standard aviation and industrial voltage born out of strapping  two 12V lead acid batteries together, and 120V is a standard domestic supply for USA and other countries so plenty of existing components and designs to work from.
What is slightly interesting is that no 400hz AC supply is mentioned, though since all power will be coming from DC solar panels it is probably easier to have any equipment that absolutely needs AC run a dedicated (and suitably sized) inverter.

it says 120V DC also in the linked document, but should it rather be 120V AC? With DC the argument "domestic supply" does not cut.

Sorry, why would strapping two 12V batteries together yield 28 volts?  Two 12s in series should give you 24 volts.

@DarthPseudonym 12V is just some average voltage, but voltage on batteries varies a lot depending on their state. While charging it might exceed 14V and get as low as 10V when the batteries are almost empty.
